# R - How to create an ascending/descending number line around a specific element in a vector

Tags: r, sequence

I have a series of the following vectors, each with a unique location of "0" surrounded by NAs:

```
NA NA NA NA NA 0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Is there a way to generate the following for each vector, i.e. a number line centered at the location of the 0, for the length of each vector?:

```
-5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

Thanks so much for any guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use :

```
x <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0 ,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
seq_along(x) - which(x == 0)
#[1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Comment: Amazing! This answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

another solution

```
seq(- which(x == 0) + 1, length.out = length(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
seq(length(x)) - which(!x)
```

Or with `which.max`

```
seq_along(x) - which.max(x)
```